# Why do my outputs look exactly the same for the Allegro 3901?

Tags: motor, oscilloscope, pulse

I am trying to capture results shown in Figure 8 of [Allegro 3901 data sheet](http://www.allegromicro.com/~/media/Files/Datasheets/A3901-Datasheet.ashx) .

My circuit looks like this:

[image]

The channels above coresspond to the oscilloscope screen captures below:

[image]
In the image above channel 3 is a PWM with Frequency = 467Hz and Duty cycle of 64%. 
As you can see channels 1 and 2 are both low (but it looks nothing like Figure 8's Ireg+ and Ireg-).

[image]
In the image above channel 3 is low and channel 4 has a PWM with the same frequency and Duty Cycle (but again channels 1 and 2 do not look like Figure 8's Ireg + and Ireg - output).

Have I wired my circuit correctly?

I also noticed Figure 8 output is measured in Amps but I'm not sure how to get my oscope to measure in Amps.

I am using a Tektronix TDS 3014B.

Comment: Maybe you need to attach a load. Current is seen through the load - your oscilloscope measures voltages across a load and by implication (if the load is purely resistance) you get current.

Comment: where in my circuit diagram would I attach the load?

Comment: Where the motor would attach

Comment: i'm not that far yet.  Before attaching the motor I feel like I should be getting results that look like Figure 8 in the data sheet.

Comment: Put a 1k ohm on just to give it a light load. Worst case scenario is it might get a tad warm. What's your voltage supply to the A3901?

Comment: The voltage supply (denoted Vbb in the circuit diagram above) is 3V.

Comment: Try 100 ohm load - max power dissipated will be 90mW

Comment: I suspect that your "Channel 1 GND" and "Channel 2 GND" should go to the chip's ground, not to an output.  If you want to see the voltage across an output, you will need to connect "out1" to one scope channel, and "out2" to another, then have the scope display the difference between those channels.  As it is, you have connected "out2" and "out4" together via the scope ground leads.